# "母牛流产了“ － "The cow cast her calf"? HSK Anki flash cards

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, usage, phrase

I'm reviewing the HSK1-limited-part1 flash card deck on Anki, and I keep coming accross this one flash card. On the front, it says

> 母牛流产了

and for the definition,

> The cow cast her calf

What does this mean (in Chinese OR English?) How is this used?

Comment: Strange. similar: 公猪配种吗? 牝马下崽哦.  I bet you will never say this in your life.

Answer (score 4):

流产 means "to have a miscarriage, to have an abortion". The former in case it happened as a natural process, the latter in case it was enforced.

So you can translate 母牛流产了 means "the cow had a miscarriage".

To cast means "To give birth prematurely" in this context, so the translation is incorrect.

This definitely is not something you need to know for HSK 1 (even for the old exam).

Comment: To add, 'to give birth prematurely' is 早产 in Chinese

Answer (score 1):

> "母牛流产了" is equals to "The mother cow abortion",

which you will probably never use this sentence in daily life, except you are working in a farm.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a constructed case to test if you can differentiate the consonants m,n,l. It's not used in everyday life unless you work on a farm